# How to create a toolbar icon / shortcut for "Server View" in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ide

I have checked a number of questions regarding server view - but my problem is not that I dont have a server view .

I do have it .

The problem is - everytime I maximise my code window - I have to go to :

> windows > show view > other > server view

This is not efficient - I want it to appear as a shortcut with an icon below the toolbar or on the left hand side in eclipse ?

Thanks